# dd with large disks

Tags: bash, dd

What is the maximum size of disks/partition with dd can work correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The limit would probably not be in `dd` but in the operating system instead.

But... for all intents and purposes it is probably more than you'll ever need. I've successfully used `dd` on raid arrays that were over `20TiB` in size.